# Regex to match all text except "x% off"

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

I am trying to write an elasticsearch pattern replace filter to remove all text from a description of a special offer, except for the x% off, so that I can query x using a range query, without any numbers that are not % off getting returned as well.

This means that I need a regex to match all text except for "x% off" or "save x%" where x is any number. Then I should be able to replace that text with an empty string.

I have written a regex which matches the words I want to keep:

```
(?:(\d+)%[-\s][Oo]ff|(?:[Ss]ave [Uu]p to|[Ss]ave)\s?(?:of\s)?(\d+)%)
```

"Get 10% off when you spend $100" -> "10% off"

"Save up to 15% on 100% pure orange juice" -> "Save up to 15%"

"Save 20% on European tours, 10% off Asian tours" -> "Save 20% 10% off"

What I need is a regex which matches everything I want to get rid of (the opposite of the expression above), so that I can replace it with a blank string and be left with either just x or just the phrases I am matching above. (Ideally I would like to be left with just "10", "15" and "20 10" instead of the above phrases, but that is not required).

Elasticsearch uses Java regular expressions, so I am using [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to test it as regex101 doesn't seem to support Java.

Comment: Just put a `.*` before and after what you have, and use capturing groups for the replacement. e.g. `.*(foo|bar).*`replacing to `"$1"` will result in either foo or bar.

Comment: @yshavit Thanks, that mostly works, the first one returns just 0 though instead of 10, adding a space before the `(\d+)` solves it for this case, but doesn't get those that start with "10% off"

Comment: I could get to this `(?:(?<=Save).*?)\d+(?=%)|\d+(?=%)(?:.*?(?=off))`, but with improvements it can match only the numbers.